# how to add some content after a field value by phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

there is a table named `product`  which has a field named `image`. the value of it  like the following:  `b3119f6547dca910c342593656`     `b3119f6547dca910c342534y`.....

now i want to add `x480.jpg` after every value. namely, `b3119f6547dca910c342593656x480.jpg`...how do i do it by phpmyadmin? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a simple SQL like this:

```
UPDATE product
SET image = CONCAT(image, 'x480.jpg')
```

Comment: when i using your code, it shows  5 rows affected. but there are many rows. why only 5 rows affected.

Comment: i looked all the data, there is no x480.jpg. when i run the command, it shows  5 row(s) affected, 260 warning(s)

Execution Time : 00:00:00:016
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:016

Comment: i find what's the reason of the error, the image field length is  set to varchar(24). when i add x480.jpg to its value, it longer  than  the default length, how to change the default length of the image?

Comment: @dreamchaser You have to go to the table structure and then click on "Edit" on the line of the field image.

Comment: oh, damn it. i add the wrong suffix. it's now like this .....image.320xx480.jpg, it‘s the wrong value. how to make it to 320x480.jpg

Comment: @dreamchaser Use the replace function but this time take care that this is exactly what you want. To test use SELECT REPLACE(image, 'image.320xx480.jpg', '320x480.jpg') FROM product. If it's ok, then use UPDATE product SET image = REPLACE(image, 'image.320xx480.jpg', '320x480.jpg')